# Why does Adobe Acrobat Pro DC sanitize and remove hidden information double document size?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, metadata

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC on Mac OS X Yosemite and find that when I run the  `Sanitize` or `Remove Hidden Information` tools the document size grows dramatically.  For example, my Acrobat file of 21 pages more than doubled from 1.67 MB to 3.94 MB and then nearly doubled again to 6.59 MB as I ran these two tools in succession.

Why would removing information cause by file size to double in size twice?  Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding what is going on here?  I would expect the files to maintain their size or shrink slightly in size with the application of these tools.

Comment: For the downvote, please suggest how to improve this question.

Comment: I don't think you're the only one. Seems others have this issue. One thing people are saying is that it converts any images (to larger, I'm not sure).

Comment: What happens when you save as optimized, and use the PDF Optimizer to do the sanitzing?